# Tkinter Menubar insert at position 0 not working

Tags: python, tkinter

When I try to insert a menu using "insert_cascade()" at position 0 the item appears at the end of the menubar instead of the start. I have tried inserting at position 0 in submenus and that works fine.

If I start the index at 1 instead of 0 then the order is correct. Anyone know why this is? I was thinking maybe index 0 of the toplevel menu is reserved but I doubt it is though.

Below is some sample code showing this in action.

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
menubar = tk.Menu(root)

filemenu = tk.Menu(menubar, tearoff=0)
data = {'label': "File", 'menu': filemenu}
menubar.insert_cascade(0, **data)

editmenu = tk.Menu(menubar, tearoff=0)
data = {'label': "Edit", 'menu': editmenu}
menubar.insert_cascade(1, **data)

aboutmenu = tk.Menu(menubar, tearoff=0)
data = {'label': "About", 'menu': aboutmenu}
menubar.insert_cascade(2, **data)

root.config(menu=menubar)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: What platform are you running this on?

Comment: When I run this code, the File menu appears before Edit and About. Are you saying that on your machine it's appearing after the About menu?

Comment: I'm using Linux (openSUSE Tumbleweed), and yes it is. I get "Edit, About, File"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `menubar` has `tearoff` set to True so the item 0 is the tearoff, though it is not visible because it is the window menubar which cannot be torn off.

If you create your `menubar` with

```
menubar = tk.Menu(root, tearoff=0)
```

instead, then the items are in the correct order.